# Session is started but i am not able to use session data in other function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I Am facing the problem with the sessions in Codeignitor project

When I try to use `addview()` function it is displaying the error page.
I have auto loaded the sessions in the config.php file

Here is my controller

```
     public function login()
    {
        $this->load->model('Reachedus_model');
        $name = $this->input->post('name');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $input = array( 'name'=>$name, 'password'=>$password);

        $data['loggedIn'] = "no";
        $chk = $this->Reachedus_model->authenticate($input);
        if($chk){
            $_SESSION['name']= $this->input->post('name');
            $this->load->view('headeradmin');
            $this->load->model('Reachedus_model');
            $data['result']=$this->Reachedus_model->getreachedus();
            $this->load->view('reached_us', $data);  

        }
        else{ 
            echo '<script>alert("Enter the valid email id and password")</script>';
            echo "<p style='color:red; text-align: center; '>Enter the valid email id and   password</p>";
            $this->load->view('adminlogin');
            }
    }   
public function addview(){
        if(!$this->session->userdata('name')){
            $this->load->view('error');
        }else{
          $this->load->view('headeradmin');
          $this->load->view('addevent');
        }
    }
 public function logout()
    {
        $this->session->unset_userdata('name');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->model('User_model');
         $data['result']=$this->User_model->getimg();
        $this->load->view('main', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

The problem is in `addview()` method.
Also i have tried with other projects but Not working.

i.e The session is not working in localhost please can i get the solution as soon as Possible

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Where are you setting the userdata `name` ? please edit your question and add the setter block.

Comment: $_SESSION['name']= $this->input->post('name'); In this i am setting the session

Comment: Did you try to use `$this->session->name` ?

Comment: No its Not Working

Comment: Looks like a little more reading on this subject is needed from [HERE](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html)   Change: `$_SESSION['name']= $this->input->post('name');` to `$this->session->set_userdata('name', $this->input->post('name'));`  and change: `if(!$this->session->userdata('name')){` to `if (!$this->session->has_userdata('name');){` you should get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the present Xampp
ANd install the updated version of Xampp

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).